# Dynamic Layout using css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a 4 column layout with a standard header and footer. Its something like this

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="leftnav"></div>
<div id="maincontent"></div>
<div id="nextcontent"></div>
<div id="addtionalinfo"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mBuf9/

But when there is no content/data in the center i want the right most div to span and take up the entire content space. And similarly if there is no content in the left most div i want the maincontent to span the remaining space. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following.

Here is the fiddle with content:

> http://jsfiddle.net/mBuf9/27/

And the same fiddle without content:

> http://jsfiddle.net/mBuf9/28/

The main change is that the divs are placed in a `table` and some small changes in css.

Hope this helps...